# Add HTTP headers while running Traefik as Ingress controller

Tags: traefik, kubernetes-ingress

I have an application running in K8S, with Traefik as load balancer as an Ingress controller.
While I ca setup easily Traefik for redirection, I need to add specific HTTP headers to all queries going through Traefik.

Is there any way to do this with Traefik?

Cheers,
Olivier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to add specific annotation from K8S in the YAML for Ingress:

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-request-headers: X-ProxyScheme:HERE_IS_MY_SCHEME||X-ProxyHost:HERE_IS_MY_HOST
ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-headers: X-ProxyScheme,X-ProxyHost,X-ProxyPort
```

As shown, if you need multiple custom headers, you must pipe them with `||`. And you need to "enable" them with annotation `ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-headers`

Cheers,
Olivier